# JQuery - Adding staggered classes to elements

Tags: jquery

I hope the title makes sense.

In short I have 5 different elements each of which is to have a different class added to it. These 5 elements will then be repeated in a series however many times needed. So in practice it will look something like this:

```html
<div class="manager red"></div>
<div class="manager blue"></div>
<div class="manager green"></div>
<div class="manager orange"></div>
<div class="manager pink"></div>

<div class="manager red"></div>
<div class="manager blue"></div>
<div class="manager green"></div>
<div class="manager orange"></div>
<div class="manager pink"></div>
```

etc...

I've been trying to use nth-child and first-of-type but without much success.

```js
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+1)').addClass('red');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+2)').addClass('blue');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+3)').addClass('green');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+4)').addClass('orange');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+5)').addClass('pink');
```

I don't think this is close so any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How bout this...

```
var classes = ['red','blue','green','orange','pink'];
$('.page-about-us .manager').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).addClass(classes[index])
});
```

or if the block of five repeats inside '.page-about-us'

```
var classes = ['red','blue','green','orange','pink'];
$('.page-about-us .manager').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).addClass(classes[index%classes.length])
});
```

Like in a structure such as this:

```
<div class="page-about-us">
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>

    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
    <div class="manager"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems like quite a nifty solution. Thanks.

Comment: oh, i see you edited the original post---I'll edit mine to reflect

Answer (score 0):

In your selector you are looking for elements with `class='manager'` inside of elements with `class='page-about-us'`

Your div's don't have a `class='manager'` so it's not selecting any elements

So depending on your structure and what you want to do

```
<div class='page-about-us'>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>
    <div class='manager'>test</div>    
</div>
```

would work with your current jQuery selectors

```
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+1)').addClass('red');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+2)').addClass('blue');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+3)').addClass('green');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+4)').addClass('orange');
$('.page-about-us .manager:nth-child(5n+5)').addClass('pink');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN52X/)

if want to filter child elements of .manager then you will need to change the selector

```
<div class='page-about-us'>
    <div class='manager'>
        <div></div> <!-- trying to target these children div -->
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Then you would want to select the children divs

```
$('.page-about-us .manager > div:nth-child(5n+1)')
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qx9hv/)

Comment: Yeah, that was just an oversight. I've corrected my post now.

Comment: @BertMurphy can an example of your show your HTML structure?  It looks like it should work in your example above.. but if they all don't have the same parent then it's a little different

Comment: @BertMurphy it all depends on how your structure and how you want the divs colored [COLOR RELEVANT TO IT'S PARENT](http://jsfiddle.net/F2eFN/)  or [COLOR NOT RELEVANT TO IT'S PARENT](http://jsfiddle.net/ke5b2/)

Comment: There isn't much more to go beyond the markup I've supplied. The only thing is a wrapping div with a class of .page-about-us. I guess I've slightly confused matters by not putting in the manager class in the first place.

It looks like I've got a number of examples to go on here so thanks to you all. Embarrassingly this includes the one I mentioned in my opening post. Not sure how I managed not to get this to work. 

Anyway, there are some interesting solutions from Ted and Gabriel which I'll have to study to understand them.

Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example that I created.
Here is the HTML code for reference:

```
<button id="add_divs">Add Divs</button>
<div class="div_container">
</div>
```

Here is the jQueryCode that you can use to execute the logic:

```
var div_container = $(".div_container");
$("#add_divs").on("click", function(e){
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        div_container.append("<div>Test"+i+"</div>");
    }
    console.log($(".div_container div:nth-child(2)").text());
    $(".div_container div:nth-child(5n+1)").addClass("red");
    $(".div_container div:nth-child(5n+2)").addClass("blue");
    $(".div_container div:nth-child(5n+3)").addClass("green");
    $(".div_container div:nth-child(5n+4)").addClass("orange");
    $(".div_container div:nth-child(5n+5)").addClass("pink");
});
```

You can run the code and accordingly check on the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/be2Lu/)